# Trying to totally reload scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a scene that represents the main menu of a game. In this menu there is an option for single player, and, when I press it, it opens a new "level 1" scene.
Also, there is a pause menu that allows the player to quit the game and get back to the main menu.
However, after it backs to the main menu, when I try to get into the level 1 scene using SceneManager.LoadScene("level 1"), it makes a lot of problems. It means that a lot of game objects don't act like they should.

I dont know why it happened, and I would appreciate if someone can help me solve it. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "a lot of problems"? You need to tell us specifically what's happening and what's not working.

Comment: For example, i have a box that if i collide it and press a specific key, it supposed to break. However it doesnt happen, i can collide the box but seems like the script doesnt work

Comment: Does the problem only start happening after you reload the scene?

Comment: Or this error: 
MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
UnityEngine.Transform.set_position (UnityEngine.Vector3 value) <0x1ccb5c00 + 0x0005a> in <dc10dd4ad9f34aa98e691e49a48c7111>:0
CrashBandicootMovementControl.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/CrashBandicootMovementControl.cs:150)

Comment: @Technoguyfication yes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SceneManager.LoadScene("level 1", LoadSceneMode.Single);` to clear the old scene and only load the new one in, which will let you get a clear scene and shouldn't have any problems.

If you have scripts that need to last into the new scene, you can use `DontDestroyOnLoad(this);` in your scripts and they will move into the new scene. The problem is you have to make sure your scripts that aren't being destroyed don't try and access destroyed objects. From your comment it looks like you have a player movement controller that isn't being destroyed, or it's being created in the menu scene and it doesn't have it's references updated correctly when the scene is reloaded. You can also use `Destroy(this);` in your scripts that are saved through scene changes to get rid of them when they're done running.

Comment: I have a qeustion, if i reload the scene as you wrote in the first row, is the start happens again?